# Percentage column labels in pgfplots bar chart

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, pgfmath, histogram

I'm working to a bar chart with datas values between 0 and 1 representing percentages like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
             bar width=1,
             ymin=0,
             enlarge x limits={abs=1},
             xtick=data,
             nodes near coords,
             nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/precision=3},
             xticklabels={A,B,C,D},
             yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
             tickwidth=0,
            ]

    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0,row sep=\\] {0.104\\0.254\\0.309\\0.271\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: bar chart's MWE output]

I need to have the values expressed as percentages on both y axis and column labels. I found the option `yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%}` to change y axis' values, but I can't figure out how to do the same for the labels. If I understand how it works, I should add a line like `\pgfmathparse{\〈something〉*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%}` in `nodes near coords` option, but I don't know what `\〈something〉` should be.

Is my hypothesis right and if it is, what is `\〈something〉`? If it isn't, how can I change labels' valure to the equivalent percentage value? Note that I need to keep all the decimals, so 0.104 must become 10.4% (not 10%).

Comment: You shoud be able to use the same with `nodes near coords={...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `nodes near coords` is `\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta`. So you can to change this to

```
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
```

and also multiply the default meta by 100 to get percentages.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
             bar width=1,
             ymin=0,
             enlarge x limits={abs=1},
             xtick=data,
             point meta=y*100,
             nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
             nodes near coords style={/pgf/number format/precision=3,
             /pgf/number format/fixed},
             xticklabels={A,B,C,D},
             yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
             tickwidth=0,
            ]

    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y index=0,row sep=\\] {0.104\\0.254\\0.309\\0.271\\};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]